# How can Mono remove files matching a regex

Tags: linux, shell, mono, rm

As part of a project, the Mono program has to write a series of images to a movie. Therefore the images are first cached in the `/tmp/` folder/ since their is a possibility that their are still images of a previous session. I want te remove these images. Therefore I use the following commands:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "rm";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/tmp/output*";
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

However when the program is executed I get the following warning: `/bin/rm: cannot remove '/tmp/output*': No such file or directory.`.

However when I executed `/bin/rm /tmp/output*` in the terminal (in user mode), the command doesn't seem to have a problem recognizing the files.

Why does this command doesn't work?

Comment: Important distinction: You're talking about "file globs", not regular expressions.  They are different animals with different syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spawning an external process for this is terrible.  Just use the standard `System.IO` APIs, for instance:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles ("/tmp", "output*")) {
    try {
        File.Delete (file);
    } catch {
        ; // optionally report error
    }
}
```

You may also use the overload that takes a `SearchOption` argument to recursively search in subdirectories.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Because you should run the shell to expand the glob pattern `/tmp/output*` into a an ordered array of file paths.

<sup>You could run `sh -c "rm /tmp/output*"` as a Mono process, but that is ugly</sup>

But you don't need a shell. You could for instance use [mono readdir](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aMono.Unix.Native.Syscall.readdir) to build an array (or a list) of file paths to remove, then remove them by calling a function doing the [unlink(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/unlink.2.html) syscall (I leave you to find how to do that in Mono).

Comment: And is their a way to do this in the Mono program? If it wasn't for the pattern recognition skills of the shell, I could write a simple File.Remove functionality in my program. However I am looking for an elegant pattern recognition system.

Comment: Certainly yes. Mono libraries provide regexprs. I forgot the details. Don't be shy, read Mono documentation.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you're not simply using the standard `System.IO` APIs ?  For instance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx.

Comment: And btw., there's `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute`, so you wouldn't ever use `sh -c ...`.